# Redeem RESTful API and Additional Information

Tags: branch.io

Wondering whether redeem RESTful API allows for additional information, such as metadata or any other key/value pairs, to be passed to Branch.io? We need to pass additional information other than branch_key, branch_secret, identity, amount, and bucket.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The referral_redeem api will require the branch_key, branch_secret, identity, amount, and bucket values to redeem credits to a specific user.  No other values are required. Reference to our documentation [Here](https://docs.branch.io/apps/deep-linking-api/#referral-redeem)

The response will be either a success or failure with an error message.

If I am misunderstanding your query please let me know.

Comment: Yes I know the requirements for redeem but I would like to store additional metadata information on branch.io side whenever I call the redeem api end-point. In other words, I would like to also pass a key, say bookingId: $someId, on top of  branch_key, branch_secret, identity, amount, and bucket values. Is that possible?